# Altering zsh's $path variable in a script that is to be sourced

Tags: zsh

I've inherited a zsh script which sets up a bunch of environment variables for some simulations.  It wants to edit the $path variable so that some perl scripts can be found:

```
typeset -U path
path=( ${SIMENV_BIN} $path )
```

However, when I source the script (`source setup.source`) the $path variable remains untouched. If I copypaste these lines to the command prompt, they *do* update $path.  If I sprinkle 'echo's in the script and source it again, the typeset command seems to clear the $path variable.

Would someone mind explaining to me what is going on, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the typeset command creates a new variable with the supplied name that is local to the current function, so changes to that variable will be lost when the function returns.  Add the `-g` option:

```
typeset -gU path
```

This will prevent localizing the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to use .zshenv since it is sourced on all invocations of the shell.

http://zsh.sunsite.dk/Contrib/startup/std/zshenv